# Python Pandas> DataFrames> map() function> Using map(dictionary) when column in dataframe as Nan values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have struggled several hours with an issue that probably has to do with how to deal with nan values in data frame when using map() function in Python Pandas.

Issue:
The data frame as show genres in three columns. Some long genre names can be replaced by broader and shorter genre names. To do this lookup I have created a dictionary in which keys are longer names and values are shorter genre names.

Then I use dataframe.map() function on each column separately and pass it the lookup dictionary.

It works well for the first column 'listed_in1'. For other two columns 'listed_in2' and 'listed_in3', the result is that both columns get filled with 'Nan' values.

I have tried long to solve it but could not make it work. I will appreciate if someone could help me figure out why the code is failing and how to fix it. Thanks.

Code:
The original data frame is big and has some null values. Below is the shorter version of my data frame in which I have used np.nan to make it look like the original data frame.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## lists to create data frame

list1=['Documentaries',
'International TV Shows',
'Crime TV Shows',
'Documentaries',
'International TV Shows',
'TV Dramas',
'Children & Family Movies',
'Dramas',
'British TV Shows',
'Comedies',
'Crime TV Shows',
'Crime TV Shows',
'Dramas',
'Children & Family Movies',
'British TV Shows',
'TV Comedies',
'Documentaries',
'Crime TV Shows',
'Thrillers',
'International TV Shows']

list2=[np.nan,
' TV Dramas',
' International TV Shows',
' Reality TV',
' Romantic TV Shows',
' TV Horror',
np.nan,
' Independent Movies',
' Reality TV',
' Dramas',
' Documentaries',
' International TV Shows',
' International Movies',
' Comedies',
' Crime TV Shows',
' TV Dramas',
' International Movies',
' Spanish-Language TV Shows',
np.nan,
' Spanish-Language TV Shows']

list3=[np.nan,
' TV Mysteries',
' TV Action & Adventure',
np.nan,
' TV Comedies',
' TV Mysteries',
np.nan,
' International Movies',
np.nan,
np.nan,
' International TV Shows',
' TV Action & Adventure',
np.nan,
np.nan,
' Documentaries',
np.nan,
np.nan,
' TV Dramas',
np.nan,
' TV Action & Adventure']

## data frame

data=pd.DataFrame({'listed_in1':list1, 'listed_in2':list2, 'listed_in3':list3})

## lookup dictionary

original_genre_names=np.array(["Action & Adventure", "Children & Family Movies", "Classic Movies", "British TV Shows", "Comedies", "Dramas", "Cult Movies", "Anime Features", "Documentaries", "Horror Movies", "Anime Series", "Classic & Cult TV", "Crime TV Shows", "International TV Shows", "International Movies", "Kids' TV", "Romantic TV Shows", "TV Action & Adventure", "TV Comedies", "TV Horror", "TV Dramas", "Independent Movies", "Reality TV", "Stand-Up Comedy & Talk Shows", "Music & Musicals", "LGBTQ Movies", "Sci-Fi & Fantasy", "Spanish-Language TV Shows", "TV Sci-Fi & Fantasy", "Romantic Movies", "Sports Movies", "Stand-Up Comedy", "Thrillers", "TV Shows", "Faith & Spirituality", "Korean TV Shows", "TV Mysteries", "Science & Nature TV", "Teen TV Shows", "TV Thrillers"])

shorter_genre_names=np.array(["Action & Adventure", "Children & Family", "Classic", "British", "Comedies", "Dramas", "Classic", "Animated", "Documentaries", "Horror", "Anime", "Classic", "Crime", "International", "International", "Children & Family", "Romantic", "Action & Adventure", "Comedies", "Horror", "Dramas", "Independent", "Reality", "Comedies", "Musical", "LGBTQ", "Sci-Fi", "International", "Sci-Fi", "Romantic", "Sports", "Comedies", "Action & Adventure", "Reality", "Spirituality", "International", "Crime", "Sci-Fi", "Children & Family", "Action & Adventure"])

'''create a lookup dictionary that matches original genres to broader genre categories.'''
dict_genres_lookup={} # dictionary
z=zip(original_genre_names,shorter_genre_names)

## dictionary comprehension method

dict_genres_lookup={a:b for a,b in zip(original_genre_names,shorter_genre_names)}
print(dict_genres_lookup)

## verifying that no data loss occured.

len(original_genre_names)==len(shorter_genre_names)

## Apart from dictionary 'dict_genres_lookup' also tried this one for lookup

series_generes_lookup=pd.Series(dict_genres_lookup, index=original_genre_names)

## Replace long genre names with shorter names

data['listed_in1']=data['listed_in1'].map(dict_genres_lookup) # this one works

## this one fails with listed_in2 all filled up with Nan values.

data['listed_in2']=data['listed_in2'].map(dict_genres_lookup)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your columns contain values with surrounding whitespaces (like `' TV Action & Adventure'`), so you need to *clean* them up (with `str.strip`) before mapping:

```
data = data.applymap(str.strip, na_action='ignore')
# Replace long genre names with shorter names
cols = ['listed_in1', 'listed_in2', 'listed_in3']
data['listed_in1'] = data['listed_in1'].map(dict_genres_lookup)
data['listed_in2'] = data['listed_in2'].map(dict_genres_lookup)
data['listed_in3'] = data['listed_in3'].map(dict_genres_lookup)
print(data)
```

---

```
            listed_in1     listed_in2          listed_in3
0        Documentaries            NaN                 NaN
1        International         Dramas               Crime
2                Crime  International  Action & Adventure
3        Documentaries        Reality                 NaN
4        International       Romantic            Comedies
5               Dramas         Horror               Crime
6    Children & Family            NaN                 NaN
7               Dramas    Independent       International
8              British        Reality                 NaN
9             Comedies         Dramas                 NaN
10               Crime  Documentaries       International
11               Crime  International  Action & Adventure
12              Dramas  International                 NaN
13   Children & Family       Comedies                 NaN
14             British          Crime       Documentaries
15            Comedies         Dramas                 NaN
16       Documentaries  International                 NaN
17               Crime  International              Dramas
18  Action & Adventure            NaN                 NaN
19       International  International  Action & Adventure
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So it was not Nan but something else. Thanks again.